# Настройка Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

подскажите кто знает какая настройка позволяет отображать все выбранный классы и файлы как на скрине , а не прятать их в выпадающий список в верхнем правом углу екрана. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как выглядит сейчас?

Answer (score 0):

В настройках File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs отключите опцию `"Показывать вкладки в одной строке" или "show tabs in single row"`